# Add full row to DataTable MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

i'm new to MVC and I am trying to build a DataTable from a stored procedure response and pass it back to my View. For the rows I build a comma delimited string full of cell values.

The issue I am having is that the string is not getting parsed by the commas, and effectively it is passing the whole string into the first cell of each row.

What is the correct way to build up a row comprised of the individual values for each column? The number of columns, their names, and amount of records returned are all variable.

```
    public ActionResult dataSet(string table, string key, string search)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection stuff");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.USP_getDataSet", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", table);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
        con.Open();

        DataTable theTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                int count = rdr.FieldCount;
                string rowString = "";
                int intRows = theTable.Columns.Count;
                //Build columns on first pass through
                if (intRows == 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        theTable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr.GetName(i).TrimEnd()), typeof(string));                    
                    }
                }

                //Grab all values for each column
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){                        
                    rowString += '\"' + (Convert.ToString(rdr.GetValue(i)).TrimEnd()) + '\"' + ", ";                        
                }

                //Remove trailing delimiter
                string finishedRow = rowString.Substring(0, rowString.Length - 2);

                //Add the full row for each time through reader
                theTable.Rows.Add(finishedRow);
           } 
        }

        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            { rdr.Close(); }
            if (con != null)
            { con.Close(); }
        }
        return View(theTable);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a more modern method of data retrieval (for example Entity Framework)?

Comment: Mainly because I don't understand how I would accomplish this with EF. The amount and names of columns are always different. Thanks for taking a look. Will give you the check mark for the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [DataRowCollection.Add(params Object[] values)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) method, each value passed in will populate each cell.  Since you are passing in a single value, it is the value of the cell.

You probably want:

```
var cells = new object[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{                        
  cells[i] = rdr.GetString(i).Trim() + "\"
}
theTable.Rows.Add(cells)
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, this works well. I did change this     rdr.GetString(i).Trim() + "\" to (Convert.ToString(rdr.GetValue(i)).TrimEnd());

Comment: No worries, I'm not exactly sure what you needed, I took my best guess at what you wanted your strings to look like.